# B2C- Log out user after "change sign in name" custom policy is run

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using the below policy to change email address/ sign in name for a logged in user. Everything works fine. I just need to be able to sign out the user after the email change is complete. I would like the user to login with the new email address.

[Change Sign in Name](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/change-sign-in-name/policy)

Is there a log out step or something that can be added to the user journey ?

Our application is a SPA in react that is using OAuth PCKE flow.

FYI. I have created a support ticket with Microsoft for this and no solution so far. Any help will be appreciated.

JasSuri Recommended this https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/issues/194 , I tried it but I am getting back the signinsignup as tfp when the user returns after "change sign in" policy is run. I followed this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/22970/how-to-add-tfp-claim-in-token-issued-by-custom-b2c-1.html) to get the tfp. Made changes to Framework extension and the signinsignup relying party file.

I need the change sign in flow to show the right tfp i.e. "Changesignin" so that I can use that to logout the user. Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Add the same change you made in your sign in/up relying party file to the change sign in relying party file. Or just revert your changes and use the acr claim which already had the policy id present.

Comment: Thanks @Sharat and please let us know if you need more information.

Comment: Hi @JasSuri-MSFT

I tried reverting the tfp configuration and tried using acr claims. The acr claim returned for changesign  is still signinsignup . The user is not logged out when they change the sign in, does that have an impact on what is returned as part of acr ? 


Thanks!

Comment: Hi @JasSuri-MSFT  Any help will be appreciated. This is a blocker for us.

Comment: If after “change sign in” the user sign in again via “sign in” policy, then the acr claim is going to reflect the sign in policy. Acr claim should always reflect the last policy id the user authenticated through.